# How can you output a constant value in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I am trying to output an array of 1280 bits, each 10 bits long, with the numbers 0->128.

I heard localparam may be the best option, but it seems like a strange request, so I'm wondering if anyone with experience may be able to help me.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *output an array*? Do you mean you have an 1280-bit output port of a module that needs to output this value, or a function/task? or just a general variable that needs this value?

Comment: I mean, I want an output where the outputs of bits 0->9 equal 0; 10-> 19 equal 1.... 1270->1279 equals 128. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that provides a constant value to a localparam or any other signal.

```
wire [1279:0] signal;

assign signal = pattern(0);

function [1279:0] pattern(input arg); // Verilog requires at least one argument to a function
integer i;
begin
     for (i=0;i<128;i=i+1)
       pattern[i*10 +:10] = i;
end
endfunction
```

SystemVerilog:

```
    wire [1279:0] signal;

    assign signal = pattern();

    function bit [1279:0] pattern(); 
      for (int i=0;i<128;i++)
           pattern[i*10 +:10] = i;
    endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  I haven't really used functions before.  They seem like they may be extraneous 'functions,' but it is good to get used to all of the facets of verilog

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for-loop in an initial or reset statement:

```
reg [0:1279] big_vector;
integer i;

// here you need an initial
// or a reset section
   for (i=0; i<128; i=i+1)
      big_vector[ i*128 +: 10] = i;
```

If you do not touch/change `big_vector` the synthesis tool will convert it to a constant.